# How to make an image slider using jquery with fadeIn and fadeOut

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have three images in my HTML and attempted to make a slider using jQuery.
Below is my code from the HTML to the jQuery.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Awesome Website</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    </head>  
    <body>      
        <div class="wrapper">
            <section id="slider">
                <img id="1" src="http://www.hdbloggers.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Background.png" alt="Important Images">
                <img id="2" src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/6935544-blue-backgrounds-hd.jpg" alt="PIGS">
                <img id="3" src="http://watermarked.cutcaster.com/cutcaster-photo-100482846-Blue-Technology-Background.jpg" alt="ROADS will be here">
            </section>
                <a href="" class="left">Previous</a>
                <a href="" class="right">Next</a>
        </div>                
        <script src="js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/slider.js"></script>  
    </body>
</html>
```

The CSS:

```
    .wrapper{
        width: 100%;
       margin:0 auto
    }
    html,body{
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
    img{
      position: absolute;
      width:100%;
      height: 100%;
      display:hidden;
    }
    #slider{
      position:relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 600px;
      display:hidden; 
    }
    #slider img{
      display:none;
    }
   .wrapper a{
      padding: 5px 10px;
      background-color:blue; 
   }
   a.left{
     top:50%;
     bottom:50%;
     float:left;
   }
   a.right{
    float:right;
   }
```

According to my jQuery, I intend to slide the images every 3 seconds but unfortunately it only shows the first image. After 3 seconds disappears and the container becomes empty. Meaning that it fades out and nothing more fades in.

```
sliderInt = 1;
sliderNext = 2;
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#slider > img#1").fadeIn(300) ;
   startSlider();           
});
function startSlider(){
    loop = setInterval(function(){      
    if(sliderNext > count){
       sliderNext = 1;
       sliderInt = 1;
    }   
    $("#slider > img").fadeOut(300); 
    $("#slider > img#1" + sliderNext).fadeIn(300);      
    sliderInt = sliderNext;
    sliderNext = sliderNext + 1;       
    },3000) 
}
```

How can I make the images keep on fading in and out?

Comment: Apparently it does..because the first image still fadesIn.
But this is also a ways that I tried which gave the same result:
$("#slider img#1" + sliderNext)

What would be the correct way?

Comment: Please add your code for live at https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: For some reason nothing appears on the jsfiddle but the it goes the link:
https://jsfiddle.net/Wosley_Alarico/j4qnu7b0/

Answer (score 0):

Please find correct code.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Awesome Website</title>
    <style>
        .wrapper
        {
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        html, body
        {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
        img
        {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            display: hidden;
        }
        #slider
        {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            height: 600px;
            display: hidden;
        }
        #slider img
        {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-rc1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <section id="slider">
            <img id="1" src="http://www.hdbloggers.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Background.png"
                alt="Important Images">
            <img id="2" src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/6935544-blue-backgrounds-hd.jpg"
                alt="PIGS">
            <img id="3" src="http://watermarked.cutcaster.com/cutcaster-photo-100482846-Blue-Technology-Background.jpg"
                alt="ROADS will be here">
        </section>
        <a href="" class="left">Previous</a> <a href="" class="right">Next</a>
    </div>
    <script>
        var sliderInt = 1;
        var sliderNext = 2;
        var count = $("#slider > img").length;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#slider > img#1").fadeIn(300);
            startSlider();
        });
        function startSlider() {
            loop = setInterval(function () {
                if (sliderNext > count) {
                    sliderNext = 1;
                    sliderInt = 1;
                }
                $("#slider > img").fadeOut(300);
                $("#slider > img#" + sliderNext).fadeIn(300);
                sliderInt = sliderNext;
                sliderNext = sliderNext + 1;
            }, 3000)
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In case any help, comment on this answer.
If you get what you intended, Please mark this answer as correct.

Comment: Please explain what you have changed and where the mistake was, just a big code block is not very helpful

Comment: I see you changed a very small thing but did not really understand why.Can you explain?

Comment: I have added this line: var count = $("#slider > img").length; and corrected this line : $("#slider > img#" + sliderNext).fadeIn(300);

Comment: Actually your anonymous function must be having values for all variable. you have used count but not defined.

Comment: Actually its all defined. If you check on the second line after the if statement there is this code : $("#slider > img#1" + sliderNext).fadeIn(300);
there was the mistake. the image show not have an id of 1. it must simply be img#...not img#1

Comment: and ..  you forgot to define count. I didn't see setting of count variable anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The jquery code should be replaced by the following:

```
  sliderInt = 1;
  sliderNext = 2;
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#slider > img#1").fadeIn(30);
      startSlider();  
  });
  function startSlider(){
    count = $("#slider > img").size();
    loop = setInterval(function(){      
    if(sliderNext > count){
        sliderNext = 1;
        sliderInt = 1;
    }   

    $("#slider > img").fadeOut(300); 
    $("#slider > img#" + sliderNext).fadeIn(300);       
    sliderInt = sliderNext;
    sliderNext = sliderNext + 1;       
  }, 3000) 
}
```

On the second line after the } of the if statement,the img cannot have an ID of 1(img#1) but simply be as img#.